# $_SESSION being destroyed by json_decode

Tags: php, json, session

I'm using sessions in php to store cart data for a website I'm building. All the data is stored as json string and is encoded/decoded using json_encode/json_decode on either end.

It appears that on one page, json_decode is erasing my session data which seems really odd. Here's the relevant bit of code which I've narrowed it down to:

```
$cart_data = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cart = json_decode($cart_data, 1);
```

I've been var_dumping $_SESSION['cart'] when testing and it looks like json_decode is affecting it even though I'm not directly telling it (without the json_decode the dump appears as a string of json, with it it appears as arrays). This is resulting in the session being destroyed when the page is refreshed or navigated away from.

I have a feeling I'm missing something fairly simple but can't spot it

Comment: Are you sure you called `session_start()` on this script and others? If you write to `$_SESSION` on this script, it won't be persisted unless you started the session properly.

Comment: definately have, I can access the $_SESSION variable

Comment: please add a `print_r($_SESSION)` immediately before and after those two lines to prove that `json_decode` is at fault.  If it's the standard version that _should_ be impossible...

Comment: Is it resetting the session, or are you getting silent errors? Try var_dump on the `$cart` to make sure it is indeed an array and not an object. I can't imagine it would make a difference as the only object I know of that PHP has a problem serializing is XML objects.

Comment: Before:

Array ( [cart] => {"no_items":2,"total_cost":690,"post_code":"","delivery_dist":0,"delivery_cost":0,"data":"","items":{"1":{"id":1,"name":"28x38ft (8.5x11.5m)","price":395,"cat":"Marquees","qty":1},"2":{"id":2,"name":"28x28ft (8.5x8.5m)","price":295,"cat":"Marquees","qty":1}}} )

Comment: After:

Array ( [cart] => Array ( [no_items] => 2 [total_cost] => 690 [post_code] => [delivery_dist] => 0 [delivery_cost] => 0 [data] => [items] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => 28x38ft (8.5x11.5m) [price] => 395 [cat] => Marquees [qty] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => 28x28ft (8.5x8.5m) [price] => 295 [cat] => Marquees [qty] => 1 ) ) ) )

Comment: So it definately is affecting the $_SESSION - var_dumping the cart produces the expected result:

array(7) { ["no_items"]=> int(2) ["total_cost"]=> int(690) ["post_code"]=> string(0) "" ["delivery_dist"]=> int(0) ["delivery_cost"]=> int(0) ["data"]=> string(0) "" ["items"]=> array(2) { [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(19) "28x38ft (8.5x11.5m)" ["price"]=> int(395) ["cat"]=> string(8) "Marquees" ["qty"]=> int(1) } [2]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(18) "28x28ft (8.5x8.5m)" ["price"]=> int(295) ["cat"]=> string(8) "Marquees" ["qty"]=> int(1) } } }

Comment: Also check echo `session.gc_maxlifetime` to make sure its not being expired immediately for some reason.

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime is set to 1440

Comment: Alright, last thing I can think of, check your session_cookie parameters to verify that your domain is set properly. Could be that it still exists, but because you are on a different part of the site it is no longer available.

Comment: Is `register_globals` activated on that server? Try renaming the variable you're assigning the result of `json_decode` to in `$cart_decoded` or whatever.

Comment: Niko you're a genius. I can't believe I spent most of my day tryna sort this out for a variable name. Add it below and I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ollie You're welcome! This is really is one of the stupidest things I've ever seen in the PHP programming language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running this script on a server with register_globals = on - that causes the variable `$cart` to be preregistered as a reference to `$_SESSION['cart']` (weird, but true). Therefore you're writing the output of json_decode() directly into the session object.

Best way to cure this is do deactivate register_globals or, if that is not possible, use a different variable name or unbind `$cart` with `unset($cart);` before assigning the new value.

Read more in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php#85448